# How do I delete a python tkinter label based on condition?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am going to use pseudo-code because my real code is a lot messier.
Basically I have a code that looks like this:

```
if i>0 and B!=1:
  #display label #1 using .grid
elif: i<0 and B!=1 :
  #display label #2 but on the same place as label#1
```

So I end up with both labels on top of each other. How do I get one of the labels to be

removed before the other label is displayed?

EDIT: Note that my program will also run in an infinite loop so both labels will be displayed through out the program's run.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `widget.destroy()` method to destroy `label1`:

```
if i>0 and B!=1:
    label1 = Tk.Label(root,text='Label1')
    label1.grid(row = 2,column=5)

elif i<0 and B!=1:
    if 'label1' in globals():
        label1.destroy()
    label2 = Tk.Label(root,text='Label2')
    label2.grid(row = 2,column=5)
```

## EDIT:

Note you could use:

```
if 'label1' in globals():
    label1.destroy()
```

To avoid a `local variable "label1" refrence before assignment` Error

Comment: I get the following error: local variable "label1" referenced before assignment, which makes sense since label1 is not created until we go into the first if statement.

Comment: @user3064033 feel free to accept and consider a upvote if this helped you.

Comment: No more errors but it does not fix the initial problem for some reason. I also tried locals() and .grid.forget() and no nothing happened.

Comment: @user3064033 if `label1.destroy()` is **called** it is certainly destroyed might be that it's note being called because `if 'label1' in globals():` evaluates to `False`